# Form в Mozilla Firefox не отправляется

Tags: php, jquery, form

Почему то с Mozilla Firefox браузера не отправляет форму.

```
<div class="modal-body">
                <form id="sending" method="post">
                    <label>&nbsp;</label><input required="required" name="fio" type="text" class="input_form " placeholder="Фамилия Имя Отчество"><br>
                     <label>&nbsp;</label><input name="email" type="text" class="input_form" placeholder="Email"><br>
                     <label>&nbsp;</label><input required="required" name="phone" type="tel" class="input_form" placeholder="Телефон 8 123 456 7890"><br>
                     <label>&nbsp;</label><input required="required" name="type" class="input_form" placeholder="Тип документа"><br>
                     <label>&nbsp;</label><textarea required="required" name="message" maxlength="200" class="textarea_form" placeholder="Примичание"></textarea><br>
                 </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Закрыть</button>
                <button type="submit" form="sending" class="btn btn-primary">Отправить</button>
            </div>

$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#sending").submit(function() { //устанавливаем событие отправки для формы с id=form
        var form_data = $(this).serialize(); //собираем все данные из формы
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST", //Метод отправки
        url: "send.php", //путь до php файла отправителя
        data: form_data
        });
     });
});


if((isset($_POST['fio']))&&(isset($_POST['email']))&&(isset($_POST['phone']))&&(isset($_POST['type']))&&(isset($_POST['message']))){
    $to = '**********@yandex.ru';
    $subject = 'Заявка';
    $message = '
            <html>
                <head>
                    <title>'.$subject.'</title>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <p>ФИО: '.$_POST['fio'].'</p>
                    <p>Email: '.$_POST['email'].'</p>
                    <p>Телефон: '.$_POST['phone'].'</p>
                    <p>Тип документа: '.$_POST['type'].'</p>
                    <p>Примичание: '.$_POST['message'].'</p>
                </body>
            </html>';
    $headers  = "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8 \r\n";
    $headers .= "From: Письмо с **** <support@*******>\r\n";
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
```

Comment: Мозилла не работает с PHP. Поэтому однозначно ответить нельзя.

Comment: @nick_n_a, Как же быть тогда? В смысле он не хочет заходить на файл post.php или что внутри.

Comment: Firefox  обрабатывает html + js - показывайте их. Детализируйте до такой степени что бы было понятно что у вас есть форма html, на форме есть ФИО и т д. Что кнопка submit правильно подвязана.

Comment: А чего авто-сабмит стоит? submit почему в ready? это что, кража личных данных? Так фокс блокирует такие фокусы.

Comment: @nick_n_a, я не знаю, честно говоря я сам бы это с 0 не написал, это взято из интернета.

Comment: Я нашёл в интернете что-то незнаю что, оно не работает, обьясните почему? Тогда ответ: код который вы привели на 50% напоминает "кражу" данных с формы. Mozilla Firefox блокирует кражу данных (код который очень на неё похож). Так как вы не написали что именно хотите - то больше ничего не могу ответить. Попробуйте в интернете взять что-то ещё.

Comment: @nick_n_a, мне нужна форма которая работает на 100% во всех браузерах, хоть самая примитивная, хоть навороченная. Кража говорите. Так можно форму то дурую использовать jquery+php? Или вы говорите php мозилла не принимает.

Comment: Если у вас трудности с использованием форм - изучите http://learn.javascript.ru/ вот http://learn.javascript.ru/forms-submit отправка форм.

Comment: @nick_n_a, трудности это мягко говоря, я знаю только html и css. Остальное тёмный лес.

Comment: Уберите со страницы js-обработчик.  В нем зашита "кража". И... скорее всего код заработает.

Comment: @nick_n_a 1 , к сожалению нет. Ладно буду думать.